# Java process.getInputStream() has nothing to read, deadlocks child

Tags: java, process, deadlock, inputstream

I am having an issue with some process wrapping, and it's only occurring in Windows XP.  This code works perfectly in Windows 7.  I'm really stumped as to why the streams are empty in XP.  I've also tried using the String[] version of Process.Exec() and it made no difference.

I am using the following class to read from the process' STDOUT and STDERR (an instance for each stream):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ThreadedStreamReader extends Thread{
 InputStream in;
 Queue messageQueue;

 public ThreadedStreamReader(InputStream s, Queue q)
 {
  in = s;
  messageQueue = q;
 }

 public void run()
 {
  try
  {
   BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String line = null;
   while((line = r.readLine()) != null)
   {
    synchronized(messageQueue)
    {
     messageQueue.add(line);
    }
   }

  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.err.println("Bad things happened while reading from a stream");
  }
 }
}
```

And I use it here:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.exe");
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();

ThreadedStreamReader stdout = new ThreadedStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), q);
ThreadedStreamReader stderr = new ThreadedStreamReader(p.getErrorStream(), q);

stdout.start();
stderr.start();

while(true)
{
    while(q.size() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println(q.remove());
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: Added synchronization

Edit: Just as an update, the parent stream readers are blocked on their read operation.  If I kill the child processes, with the task manager, they read in the null from the closing of the stream.

Comment: +1 for having a good detailed question showing that you've thought through the potential issues that could arise here.

Comment: After sitting here scouring the internet for answers, I randomly stumbled upon the problem.  I have not figured out the solution, only a workaround, but at least i'm up and running.  One of the parameters I was passing to the program caused it to hang.  I took the parameter out, which wasn't optimal for what i'm trying to do, but the program doesn't hang anymore.  That same parameter worked on my Win7 box, so I didn't even think that was part of it. Oh well, thanks for the help!

Comment: What kind of parameter did you remove? I had some strange and silly problems with deadlocks in Java (all had one thing in common: Reading from System.in)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a threadsafe data structure; I don't think LinkedList is threadsafe.

Comment: I have updated the code to synchronize.  It still has the same issue. :\

Answer (score 1):

One mistake that strikes me is that [`LinkedList` is not synchronized](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), but you're trying to write to it in 2 threads.

Another thing to keep in mind is `Process.getInputStream()` returns the `stdout` stream of the process, so you should rename the variable currently called `stdin` to `stdout` to prevent confusion.

Comment: yeah, I got confused by the use of "stdin". From your Java program's point of view, it's an input stream, but from the Process's point of view it's stdout.

Comment: I have changed stdin to stdout along with adding synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

There are known bugs in pre-Vista Windows operating systems where loading DLLs can cause a hang in IO.

e.g. see http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/09/28/reading-stdin-may-cause-your-jvm-hang and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94701/loadlibrary-deadlocks-with-a-pipe-read

I'm not sure if this is what you are running in to, but it may be related.

Also, I vaguely recall some issues in getting a valid stdin and stdout from non-console windows applications. If your call to 'test.jar' is using 'javaw' rather than 'java', then this could be the cause of your problem, too.

Comment: Oh, I just used test.jar as an example.  That is good to know, though.

Comment: Reading System.in is often a problem. More links to SUN-ug reports in my answer of this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836780/serversocket-blocked-by-thread-seeking-input-from-console/4078869#4078869

Answer (score 1):

Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.