# ServerSocket blocked by thread seeking input from console

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking, serversocket

Can anyone give me insight into why the ServerSocket constructor never returns in the new thread? (I never see the "Opened" message printed to the console.) It seems the main thread prevents the server socket thread from running by entering into readLine too quickly:

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      new Thread(new SocketOpener()).start();

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String inLine = br.readLine();
      System.out.println(inLine);
   }
}

public class SocketOpener implements Runnable
{

   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         System.out.println("Opening...");
         ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(4444);
         System.out.println("Opened");
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         System.out.println("IO Error");
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in? I pasted your code into Eclipse (removing the word `public` from `public class SocketOpener...` to get it in a single file) and have no problem seeing the `Opened` print statement.

Comment: I just ran this and it works fine for me...

Comment: Running on Windows XP, Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02), Java HotSpot Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's the ServerSocket constructor that blocks, but the System.out.println("Opened"). The fact that the main thread is trying to read from System.in prevents outputs to be done on System.out.

Comment: This may be possible, though it seems a bit strange. To verify, try typing something to console & hitting enter. If "Opened" pops up, you've probably got your answer.... Edit: Well, I tried putting break points in both threads, running the main thread and stopping the SocketOpener thread until main was waiting for input, then continued on. I saw no problems. Could be an artifact of using Eclipse rather than raw javac.

Comment: I typed something in the console and pressed enter and I do see the opened message. However I have just discovered that if I use Scanner instead of BufferedReader it works without me typing anything. Odd

Comment: As mentioned in my answer it could be http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4939977 I don't know if the ServerSocket-Constructor call InetAddress.getLocalHost(), but it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from System.in causes a lot of problems:
Under some circumstances you can't:

1. Create a Temp-File (because of 2)
2. Read the Inet4Adress of your maschine
3. Load a DLL

I've encountert some of this Problems with Windows Server 2003 and older. This happens because of some Bugs in the Win32-API ans Java-VM.

But there may be an easy workarround:

Only call System.in.read(), if System.in.availiable() returns a value larger than 0.

- [Deadlock between
  System.loadLibrary() and
  System.in.read()](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4809647)
- [Inet4AddressImpl.getLocalHostName is
  hanging intermittenly](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4939977)
- [Deadlock
  in Win32](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94701/loadlibrary-deadlocks-with-a-pipe-read)

Comment: WindowsXP is problematic as well. For Windows Server 2003 installing all updates helped a lot.