# Calling cat from a shell which is in turn called by java exec

Tags: java, shell, exec

I have a shell script test.sh that does:

```
cat /home/tomcat/temp/tempLogFile.log > /home/tomcat/temp/logFile_test.log
```

I call test.sh from java by Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.sh")

It creates the logFile_test.log but nothing written to it.

If I run the script directly from shell, it works fine.
What could be going wrong?

Thanks,

UPDATE: Interstingly, it works fine if I do

```
echo 'cat /home/tomcat/temp/tempLogFile.log > /home/tomcat/temp/logFile_test.log' | at now
```

But I cant use `at now` since I need to wait for cat to finish

Comment: Maybe add 2>&1 and look in the file to see if the cat prints an error message

Comment: I tried 2>&1 but still nothing. no errors. Even the exit status from the process from Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.sh") is 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your command path is messed up? That command will create logFile_test.log even if it can't run the `cat` program. Try adding something like:

```
set > /tmp/dump.txt
```

to the shell script. This will write a copy of the process's environment variables to `/tmp/dump.txt`. Inspecting those might help you figure out the problem.

Another possibility is that the disk is full. In that case, you'd be able to create empty files, but not write any data to them.

Comment: I tried it. set > /tmp/dump.txt dumps the contents into the file alright. But just that cat on file and dumping its contents using redirection is not working

Answer (score 0):

Once you invoke the `getRuntime().exec("ANY_COMMAND");` , it returns you an instance of Process, using process object you can  get Input and Output Streams and then pass any other command to the same process or read the output , for that purpose you have three streams connected

1. Output Stream :- Gives you Control to send more arguments or commands to the same process
2. Input Stream :- Gives you Control to read the values from the stdout of the process
3. Error Stream :- Gives you all the errors that were occured during execution of any command.

even if you have any errors, you can check the error stream and see whats going wrong.

you may refer [Java process.getInputStream() has nothing to read, deadlocks child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756899/java-process-getinputstream-has-nothing-to-read-deadlocks-child)

Comment: Yes I tried getting the output from error stream but nothing in there. Even the Process's exit status returns 0